# Why do images open when i click on them in my JS gallery?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the simplest JS gallery of images that is supposed to show a big image on top and small thumbnails of other gallery images on the bottom. The bottom image i hover over becomes the big image which is fine but when i click on it it opens the image itself in the new url(on the same page) even though i didn't implement anything like that in my JS.

Here is html:

```
<p><img id="largeImg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal1.jpg') }}" alt="Image 1"></p>

<ul id="thumbs">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal1.jpg') }}" title="Image 2"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal1.jpg') }}"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal2.jpg') }}" title="Image 3"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal2.jpg') }}"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal3.jpg') }}" title="Image 4"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal3.jpg') }}"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal4.jpg') }}" title="Image 5"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal4.jpg') }}"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal5.jpg') }}" title="Image 6"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='metal5.jpg') }}"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JS:

```
thumbs.onmouseover = function(event) {
    let thumbnail = event.target.closest('a');

    if (!thumbnail) return;
    showThumbnail(thumbnail.href, thumbnail.title);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function showThumbnail(href, title) {
    largeImg.src = href;
    largeImg.alt = title;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that something should be handled different? There is a `a` tag around your images that handles opening the image

Comment: the code isn't mine it's from JS book, here's the example of it working correctly without opening images: https://plnkr.co/edit/TY1qW8y0Oas4x9GS?p=preview&preview

Comment: yeah, in the working code, it is `thumbs.onclick`, and not `thumbs.onmouseover`... implement the `thumbs.onclick` with only `event.preventDefault();` in it and it should work

Comment: You have added anchor tag with href as a parent of your img. it's default property of anchor tag to be redirected on the given URL on click. Remove anchor tag & use custom attribute to pick image URL.

Comment: Yes it's what @Argee says. You prevent `mouseover` now instead of `click`

Comment: @Agree its true and the code works when i do the onclick version( the images change ) but the big one still opens seperately

Comment: @YogendraChauhan so can i do it with something like a <p> tag that would have a custom attribute like "limk" that would store my link? What would JS code look like?
Something like this? `thumbs.onclick = function(event) {
    let thumbnail = event.target.closest('p');

    if (!thumbnail) return;
    showThumbnail(thumbnail.limk, thumbnail.title);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function showThumbnail(href, title) {
    largeImg.src = limk;
    largeImg.alt = title;
}`

Comment: Yes, but use **<div>** instead of **<p>** tag. Like **<div link="your_link"><img/></div>**

Comment: @YogendraChauhan why **<div>**? I got it to semi-work your way but it still doesn't show the image, only the title changes

Comment: @ЯрославДемцюх You are accessing custom attribute directly, which can't be accessed directly, you should use javascript **getAttribute()** method to get attribute value. See example in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```js
var thumbs = document.querySelector("ul#thumbs");
thumbs.onmouseover = function(event) {
    let thumbnail = event.target.closest('li');
    if (!thumbnail) return;
    showThumbnail(thumbnail.getAttribute('data-link'), thumbnail.title);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function showThumbnail(href, title) {
    console.log('href: ', href, ' title: ', title);
    largeImg.src = href;
    largeImg.alt = title;
}
```

```css
ul#thumbs {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#thumbs li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <img id="largeImg" src="" alt="Image 1">
</p>

<ul id="thumbs">
    <li data-link="https://dummyimage.com/4:3x1080" title="Image 2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300">
    </li>
    <li data-link="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080" title="Image 3">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300">
    </li>
    <li data-link="https://dummyimage.com/2:6x1080" title="Image 4">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300">
    </li>
</ul>
```